# C# any method recognizing the number base?

Tags: c#, string, integer

**I am not asking: "how to convert string to the integer knowing the base"**

Quick question

I wrote my own one but just wondering if there is a method converting from the c# syntax string literal (ie "0x34", "0b101010" or "5675676") to the integer, automatically detecting the base. I have not found any, and I had to write my own one.

It is not the dupe as I am looking for the method **which will automatically recognize the base** (if it has the correct C# syntax of course). If I have to - there is no difference in writing the own one.

examples:

"0b1101010" - will convert it as 2 base string

"0x5454335" - will convert it as 16 base string

"34535534" - will convert it using 10 base string

Comment: string binary = Convert.ToString(5, 2); // convert 5 to its binary representation

Comment: As far a I know you need to manually handle each case

Comment: @harold I wrote the function as I have not found any, but I am just curious  is any "standard" exists.

Comment: My understanding of the question is that he wants the actual number represented regardless of what base/format it's in. The .Net framework lacks any built in way to do this so it'd have to be done manually.

Comment: @PhonicUK - +1 Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "*to the number*"? The bits in 1101010 have very different values when converted to an int vs a float vs a double.

Comment: @Crowcoder I meant the "sane" conversions.

Comment: I do not think there is one. Even though the idea might be great for you now it doesn't in the long run as sometimes it might be confused by base 7 being interpreted as base 10 for example. **EDIT** what I meant is that you would have to make same indication as in the other two examples you've made, eg. `0x` being base 16 and, let's say, `7x` being base 7.

Comment: @Mateusz do you know that the in C# there are only three integer constants formats binary, hex and decimal. There is no 7 base one. So your comment is 100% off topic.

Comment: @P__J__ You're wrong with this one, Roslyn compiler had it's interpreter for ( If I remember correctly ) octal values.

Comment: I have working C++ code. If you want I can share it with you & you can rewrite it in C# as well.

Comment: doesn't int.Parse() or int.TryParse() work for this?

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski Thank you very much, but I do not need it. I wrote (before asking) my own method. But was just curious if there is a "standard" one.

Comment: @kenny to be honest I did not try this ones.

Comment: @Mateusz C# in the Microsoft standard has only those three formats. No octal numbers. Some third party compilers/interpreters may have extended the standard, but it is not the scope of this question. BTW base 7 != octal